# Pytest - preserve a fresh copy of a file b/w tests, read from disk once

Tags: pandas, pytest

I want to read a large pandas dataframe from file, and then send it to each test that I run as a fixture. I would like a fresh version of the original df taken from memory, not read from disk.

Something like this:

```
import pytest

# <something here>
...
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv)
...

def test_1(df_fixture):
  assert len(df_fixture) == 1_000_000

def test_2(df_fixture):
  # Want a fresh df, without reading from disk again 
  assert sum(df_fixture["col1]) == 10_000_000
```

Comment: You can make a fixture (scope=function) that in each test you call it will return a copy of the original df

Comment: Should the line: `df=pd.read()` be wrapped in a fixture or can it be at the top of the file?

Comment: on top of the file so it will read only once

Comment: you can also  put your main df in fixture with scope=session and the copy df in scope=function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your main df in fixture with scope=session and the copy in another fixture with scope=function. in the test call the fixture of the copy

```
import pandas as pd
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def get_main_df():
    yield pd.read_csv("data.csv")


@pytest.fixture
def get_df_copy(get_main_df):
    yield get_main_df.copy(deep=True)


def test_1(get_df_copy):
  assert len(get_df_copy) == 1_000_000

def test_2(get_df_copy):
  assert sum(get_df_copy["col1"]) == 10_000_000
```